How to reuse switch block labels without goto?
How to implement the following code without goto and unnecessary code complexity?
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        bool keyA = false;
        bool keyB = false;
        // ...
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg.ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    case "-a":
                        if(keyA) break;
                        keyA = true;
                        // do here also what the A key requires
                        break;
                    case "-b":
                        if(keyB) break;
                        keyB = true;
                        // do here also what the B key requires
                        goto case "-a"; // key B includes the action of key A
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The only thing that suggests itself is to duplicate the lines of code from key A to key B or use stuffing everything into methods, but this doesn’t look convenient and compact to view.

What if someone uses the a and b flags together?

"convenient and compact" is certainly debatable. My go would be presumably be to clean up the args first (removing duplicates and args contained in other args. And then have a switch or something like that that calls fitting methods or in the case of -b two methods. The complete key remembering and gotos stuff is gone then.

You COULD set up a class and use configuration ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration
then work using that IConfiguration commandconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()  .AddCommandLine(args)  .Build();  var cmdConfig = commandconfig.Get<MyConfiguration>();  Debatable on the more code part but this could also be utilized to read a JSON config file for example.  Value here is no magic strings like "-a" "-b" etc. cmdConfig.A etc. or MyCoolMethod(cmdConfig)

I came up with a solution to my question: using local functions. This allowed me to avoid significant code refactoring and goto usage. One of the main advantages of local functions is that they have access to variables created in the method where they are defined. Unlike regular functions, local functions can “see” these variables. At the same time, the code remains close to the original.
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static bool keyA = false;
        static bool keyB = false;
        // ...
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int someOption = 0;
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg.ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    case "-a":
                        void KeyA()
                        {
                            if (keyA) return;
                            keyA = true;
                            someOption = 1; // so it's possible
                            // do here also what the A key requires
                        }
                        KeyA();
                    break;
                    case "-b":
                        if (keyB) break;
                        keyB = true;
                        // do here also what the B key requires
                        KeyA(); // key B includes the action of key A
                    break;
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


In order to accomplish what you want, I suggest that you put everything inside of switchCaseA in a function. This will allow you to call this logic in switchCaseA & switchCaseB. Such as:
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        bool keyA = false;
        bool keyB = false;
        // ...
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg.ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    case "-a":
                        if(keyA) break;
                        keyA = true;
                        ReusableMethodA();
                        break;
                    case "-b":
                        if(keyB) break;
                        keyB = true;
                        // do here also what the B key requires
                        
                        ReusableMethodA();
                    // ...
                }

            }
        }

      private static void ReusableMethodA()
      {
         //do all of your logic here:
      }
    }
}


Thank you for giving me the idea, after thinking in this direction I decided to use local functions. They can be placed anywhere inside the main function, which allows to preserve the original design.
